# Should we have a lot shells in our Ubuntu server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security

I have these shell in my VM

```
# /etc/shells: valid login shells
/bin/sh
/bin/bash
/bin/rbash
/bin/dash
/usr/bin/tmux
/usr/bin/screen
/bin/zsh
/usr/bin/zsh
```

Is it a good thing ? Should I safely remove any of this extra shell?

I think I only use `bash` Do they come automatically with Ubuntu ?

Comment: As at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/559624/5132 , the notion of just going around deleting stuff _with zero attempt to understand what it is_ is a poor one.  _What does it mean for something to be listed in `/etc/shells`?_ is a quite different question, which you aren't even asking.  (Contrast https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/414643/5132 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/319735/5132 .)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, this is a fine number of shells.  `dash` is the default `/bin/sh` implementation, and `bash` is the default interactive shell, and together these account for the first four items.  `zsh` is a common user shell with a lot of features, and many experienced users are likely to use it.

`tmux` and `screen` are terminal multiplexers that allow users to switch between multiple terminal windows.  They are very commonly used, and are listed in `/etc/shells` because some people set them as their shell so they're always launched on login.

The only thing that having these in `/etc/shells` does is allow users to set them as their login shell if they're installed.  All of these are commonly used and considered secure for normal users.  If you have security concerns about the packages, you can remove them (for `zsh`, `tmux`, and `screen`) and that will prevent folks from using them.  `dash` and `bash` are considered essential, and if you try to remove them, you will break your system.

I consider myself quite security conscious, and I have all of these programs on my system without concern, and I administer systems for my job that have all of these as well.  As long as you have security updates regularly applied, there should be no problem.